# Break foreach C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv, for-loop, foreach

I created a foreach that reads me the various fields inside a .csv file and inserts them into an xml file.
I wanted to know if there was the possibility of blocking the cycle after a series of lines read (eg 10).
how can I do?

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
lines.RemoveAt(0);
        

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(savepath, Encoding.UTF8);

writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("DC8_Recipe");

foreach (var line in lines){
    var csvItem = line.Split(';');
           
    writer.WriteStartElement("DC8_Recipe");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("PlantNo", "01");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("FactoryNo", "01");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("No", csvItem[0].Replace('"', ' '));
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", csvItem[2]);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("ShortName", csvItem[3]);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("RecipeSetValueRow");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("SetValue", csvItem[12]);
    writer.WriteStartElement("Material");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("No", csvItem[10]);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();

}

writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break

Comment: Or use [.Take(10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take)

Comment: adding `break;` didn't work?

Comment: use async await ?

Comment: i recommend using a csv reader instead of splitting lines yourself. you'll save yourself a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: @fmansour how I can use it? and where?

Comment: declare `int counter=0;` before foreach, and add `if (counter++)>10 break;` before foreach closing tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what you are asking.

#1 -
decalre a counter `int counter=0` and use this variable to as a condition for breaking out of the loop
`if ((counter++) > 10 ) {break;}`

#2 (the recommended way) -
Use `.Take(10)` calling `Take()` on IEnumerable will return the specified number of contiguous elements

copy past the code below and try it for yourself

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
            lines.RemoveAt(0);


            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(savepath, Encoding.UTF8);

            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("DC8_Recipe");

            foreach (var line in lines.Take(10))
            {
                var csvItem = line.Split(';');

                writer.WriteStartElement("DC8_Recipe");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("PlantNo", "01");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("FactoryNo", "01");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("No", csvItem[0].Replace('"', ' '));
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", csvItem[2]);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("ShortName", csvItem[3]);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteStartElement("RecipeSetValueRow");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("SetValue", csvItem[12]);
                writer.WriteStartElement("Material");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("No", csvItem[10]);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();

            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Or even `File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1).Take(10).ToList();`

Comment: Or better still: use [`ReadLines(path)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines) instead of ReadAllLines - then you don't even read all other lines